# Overwrite file, but only parts that are not spaces

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, streamwriter, overwrite

I am looking for a way to overwrite certain parts in a .dat file with 00000. For this I have a StringBuilder with content like this:

```
"00000000            0000000000000000          "
```

Now I am looking for a method that overwrites the parts in the file with zeroes, and justs keeps the content of the parts with spaces.

So if I have

```
"AUEUIGHEVjerhvgm,eiouhegfwoedjkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjje"
```

I want it to turn into

```
"00000000Vjerhvgm,eio0000000000000000jjjjjjjjjje"
```

Does such a method exist? Or should I accomplish this task in another way?

Comment: If your logic is not too complex you can Open the file and use Regex with replace

Comment: what is the criteria exactly??

Comment: I can imagine Zip from LINQ being somewhat useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var byteCharZero = Convert.ToByte('0');
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("         00000000            0000000000000000 ");
using (var fileStream = File.Open("D:\\file.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
  var length = Math.Min(stringBuilder.Length, fileStream.Length);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (stringBuilder[i] == '0')
    {
      fileStream.Position = i;
      fileStream.WriteByte(byteCharZero);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I am looking for. Now I want to replace more than one line. (e.g., row 2 till 207) with this pattern. Any tips on which method to use?

Comment: Thanks. It took 30 minutes on my file ;-).

Comment: Hmm it made a mistake at line 100. Can it be that this program makes a mistake because of starting another file reader in another visual studio screen for example?

Comment: > Thanks. It took 30 minutes on my file ;-).

Comment: Sorry, I've submitted prev. comment by mistake.  

> Thanks. It took 30 minutes on my file ;-).  
Wow, it shouldn't take so long, unless your file is huge.  
  
>Can it be that this program makes a mistake because of starting another file reader  
No, because you are not able to open another file stream, you will get IOException "The process cannot access the file".  

Could you show your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I think your specification is slightly in error, but it seems that you want something like this:

```
var pattern   = new StringBuilder("         00000000            0000000000000000 ");
var target    = "AUEUIGHEVjerhvgm,eiouhegfwoedjkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjje";
var workspace = new StringBuilder(target);

for (int i = 0, n = Math.Min(pattern.Length, target.Length); i < n; ++i)
    if (pattern[i] != '0')
        workspace[i] = '0';

string result = workspace.ToString();
```

In this example, result will be `000000000jerhvgm,000000000000jkjjjjjjjjjjjjjj0e` which isn't what your example states - but I think your example is slightly wrong...

Comment: Ha you are right ;-). This is what I want. And I've updated the example to reflect what I want

Comment: The issue is though that there are also fillers of spaces. Then I cannot do `if (pattern[i] != '0')`. I should find a character that does not exist in the file and then use that in the method of drbald below as `if (stringBuilder[i] != '[chosenCharater]') then replace`.