# How to overwrite each line in a file with a string

Tags: c#, filestream, overwrite

I have a string pattern that has to be overwritten from the second to 207th line of a file.

Currently I have [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577249/overwrite-file-but-only-parts-that-are-not-spaces) to overwrite every 0, 1 or space in the full pattern (which is 207 lines of 3000 length each).

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath + fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var minLength = Math.Min(pattern.Length, fileStream.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Started overwriting file " + fileName);
            for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
            {
                fileStream.Position = i;

                if (pattern[i] == '0')
                {
                    fileStream.WriteByte(byteCharZero);
                }
                else if (pattern[i] == '1')
                {
                    fileStream.WriteByte(byteCharOne);
                }
                else if (pattern[i] == ' ')
                {
                    fileStream.WriteByte(byteCharSpace);
                }
            }
        }
```

This method works like a charm, till line 110. Then it jumps back one space and on line 161 it does the same thing again. That way the pattern is not in the correct place.

I don't know why this is, but I will approach the problem in another way to solve it:

Now I want to overwrite the second till 207th line with a string pattern that consist of one line. How do I accomplish overwriting separate linse in the method above?

Comment: What is the character encoding used for the file?

Comment: @MatthewWatson UTF-8.

Comment: You seem to only refer to byte offsets in the file - there's nothing in there that is detecting *lines*... can you clarify?

Comment: No I am not detecting lines. Now I just use bite offset (position) in the pattern I created and look for the position the pattern, and then overwrite that position in the file as well to overwrite. This goes wrong at line 110 somehow someway. That is why I want to try overwriting line by line, and I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about "lines", so the first thing to check is the line-endings. Is it, perhaps, that the line-endings are usually CRLF, except for near line 161 where it is just CR or LF? A different line-ending would certainly account for an off-by-one.

Comment: That is a good point. I use Sublime Text and line-endings are set to Windows. I will try to get a text editor which can display line-endings.

Comment: I checked. They are all clrf. Both the pattern and the file. And I am 100% sure all lines are same length. It is a mysterious issue.

Comment: @user then also check the line endings in your pattern. Ultimately, there's an off by one somewhere, and it isn't in the code we can see.

Comment: I did. I printed the pattern to a file and there I can see that the line endings are also clrf. Wait, now I see something. There is a mistake in the output file. On line 110 it becomes CRL instead of CRLF... How can this be? The input file is correct, and the pattern created printed to a file is correct. The line endings in the pattern are created by `AppendLine()` on a stringbuilder. I changed it to `Append("\r\n")` and will see if that helps. It is strange that it only happens on line 110 while I use a for-loop to create the pattern. The input file also has crlf on every line.

Comment: @user2609980 "CRL" doesn't even make sense, since [CR] is one character, and [LF] is one character; [CRL] isn't even meaningful... what do you mean, in bytes, by CRL ?

Comment: Well, in notepad++ it displays as CRL. Do not know how I acn see the bytes. But thanks for your help, we decided to only use the first 100 lines and circumvent the issue that way. The file is an example file and 100 lines is enough.

Comment: @user2609980 to get at the actual bytes, the `FileStream` you have should be fine

Comment: I will collect the byte value later.